# typescript throwing warning on passing obj['key'] in loop

Tags: javascript, typescript

I often have this problem getting warning from TS when accessing property of object in loop. I know the reason but I have no clue how to solve it.

```
const errs = {
    'a': {},
    'b': {},
    'c': {},
    'd': {}
  }

  const errsInGroup = {
    'g1': ['cn', 'z', 'a'],
    'g2': ['ee','sf']
  }

  const oneErr = errsInGroup['g1'].some(val => errs[val]) //typescript error

  console.log(oneErr) //true
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/4r15d?file=/index.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object that you are using: `errs` does not have a type defined which defaults the type of the keys being used inside that object to `any`.

So when you use `.some(val` the `val` is of type `string` and when it is referenced in `errs[val]` the val is passed as `string` but `errs` has defaulted the type of the keys to `any`. Thus the TypeScript error.

To solve this, you need to get into the habit of defining types explicitly.

```
const errs: any = {
    'a': {},
    'b': {},
    'c': {},
    'd': {}
}
```

Now `errs` can accept `any` type of keys including `string`.

Comment: can I cast errs says errs is coming from a package which I don't have control.

Comment: Sure that would work too.
`const localErrors: any = errs;` and then you replace `errs[val]` with `localErrors[val]` inside the `.some()` function.

Comment: it's dirty but as least it worked, no way to directly cast it than need to declare a temporary variable?

Comment: Not that I can think of without having more details.

Comment: `import { errs } from 'some-package'` //can't cast it here?

Comment: Well if you have access to `some-package` then you might as well set it there. But unless the object has a defined type/interface I'm not sure if it can be at the time of import.